# new to Linux and ROS, Can't install Lunar

Tags: ros, installation, ros-lunar, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the installation instructions on this website
http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Ubuntu

but when I try to install the Full Desktop version I get this error.
I don't know what to do.

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-9ubuntu2.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 hddtemp
 sbcl
 ros-lunar-roslisp
 ros-lunar-diagnostic-common-diagnostics
 ros-lunar-ros-comm
 ros-lunar-ros-core
 ros-lunar-diagnostics
 ros-lunar-ros-base
 ros-lunar-perception
 ros-lunar-viz
 ros-lunar-robot
 ros-lunar-desktop
 ros-lunar-simulators
 ros-lunar-desktop-full
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269384/new-to-linux-and-ros,-can%27t-install-lunar/) by [ddimassa](https://answers.ros.org/users/31668/ddimassa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-08-22**:
It looks like there was an error while installing packages, but I don't see the actual error in your question. Can you edit your question to include the full error message?

**Comment by [ddimassa](https://answers.ros.org/users/31668/ddimassa/) on 2017-08-27**:
thanks for responding. yes, there were in fact package errors.
So, I basically rebooted my machine and started the whole process over from the beginning and then it worked.
So, I have no idea what caused the problem, but it seems to have fixed itself.
that just sounds wrong..... but it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try to use one of the available mirrors:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation/UbuntuMirrors

(I have been experiencing - from the EU - several issues with aborted downloads from the main site today, which went away as soon as I switched to a European mirror.)

I hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [fibo](https://answers.ros.org/users/31677/fibo/) with karma: 16 on 2017-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0